# How to combine two simular Sub Procedures together

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sub procedures that alter the layout of a person's name.  The first on changes First Name to Last Name, First Name by look for a space " " between the First and Last Name.

```
Sub FlipNames()  'FN LN to LN, FN
'Purpose: Converts selected cells First Name Last Name in place to Last Name, First Name

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim sCell As String
    Dim sLast As String
    Dim sFirst As String
    Dim rCell As Range

    For Each rCell In Selection     'sets range to selection
        sCell = rCell.Value
        x = InStr(sCell, " ")       'searches for space
        If x > 0 Then               'flips order
            sFirst = Left(sCell, x - 1)
            sLast = Mid(sCell, x + 1)
            rCell.Value = sLast & ", " & sFirst 'places comma in between LN, FN
        End If
    Next
    Set rCell = Nothing             'resets the range to zero
End Sub
```

The second sup procedure looks for a comma "," between the two names (ex: Last Name, First name) and flips it back to First Name Last name order.

```
Sub FlipNames2()  'LN, FN to FN LN
'Purpose: Converts selected cells Last Name, First Name in place to First Name Last Name

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim sCell As String
    Dim sLast As String
    Dim sFirst As String
    Dim rCell As Range

    For Each rCell In Selection     'sets range to selection
        sCell = rCell.Value
        x = InStr(sCell, ",")       'searches for comma
        If x > 0 Then               'flips order
            sFirst = Left(sCell, x - 1)
            sLast = Mid(sCell, x + 1)
            rCell.Value = sLast & " " & sFirst 'places space in between FN LN
            rCell.Value = LTrim(rCell)         'trims off leading spaces
        End If
    Next
    Set rCell = Nothing             'resets the range to zero
End Sub
```

What I would like help with is combine these two separate sub procedures into one using an If Else (maybe something else?) to test for the space or comma to choose which part of the code to run.  Thanks, I am looking forward to seeing your ideas.

Comment: Does any of the answer below suit your question? If so, I'd recommend marking one of the answer as accepted to give closure to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be thinking on the right lines. Refactoring might be a good idea since the methods are so similar. Try this:

```
' FlipMethod cases handled:
'  If "FN LN to LN, FN" is supplied: John Smith will be converted to Smith, John
'  If "LN, FN to FN LN" is supplied: Smith, John will be converted to John Smith
Sub FlipNames(FlipMethod as String)  'FN LN to LN, FN
'Purpose: Converts selected cells First Name Last Name in place to Last Name, First Name

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim sCell As String
    Dim sLast As String
    Dim sFirst As String
    Dim rCell As Range

    For Each rCell In Selection     'sets range to selection
        sCell = rCell.Value

        if FlipMethod = "FN LN to LN, FN" then
            x = InStr(sCell, " ")       'searches for space
        else
            x = Instr(sCell, ",")       ' searches for comma
        end if

        If x > 0 Then               'flips order
            sFirst = Left(sCell, x - 1)
            sLast = Mid(sCell, x + 1)

            if FlipMethod = "FN LN to LN, FN" then
                rCell.Value = sLast & ", " & sFirst 'places comma in between LN, FN
            else
                rCell.Value = sLast & " " & sFirst 'places space in between FN LN
                rCell.Value = LTrim(rCell)         'trims off leading spaces
            end if

        End If
    Next
    Set rCell = Nothing             'resets the range to zero
End Sub
```

---

There may be some value in separating the functionality of name formatting and iteration over multiple cells. Here's an example of functionality separated from iteration.

```
Enum NameFormat
    FNLN_TO_LNFN_WITH_COMMA = 1
    LNFN_WITH_COMMA_TO_FNLN = 2
End Enum

Function FlipNames(Data As String, NameFormat As Long) As String

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim sLast As String
    Dim sFirst As String

    ' Exit early if data is improper
    If IsNull(Data) Or Len(Trim(Data)) = 0 Then
        FlipNames = Data
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Check if comma or space is present, depending on requirements
    Select Case (NameFormat)
        Case FNLN_TO_LNFN_WITH_COMMA
            x = InStr(Data, " ")
        Case LNFN_WITH_COMMA_TO_FNLN
            x = InStr(Data, ",")
        Case Else
            FlipNames = Data
            Exit Function
    End Select

    ' Exit early if required split character not found
    If x <= 0 Then
        FlipNames = Data
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Find first and last names
    sFirst = Trim(Left(Data, x - 1))
    sLast = Trim(Mid(Data, x + 1))

    ' Put data together as desired
    Select Case NameFormat
        Case FNLN_TO_LNFN_WITH_COMMA
            FlipNames = sLast & ", " & sFirst
        Case LNFN_WITH_COMMA_TO_FNLN
            FlipNames = Trim(sLast & " " & sFirst)
    End Select

End Function
```

When there is a need to add more functionality

- add a enumerated constant to indicate the kind of format that is needed
- add code to split data
- add code to rejoin data

Moreover, you can add test cases to ensure that this function does what is desired for different incoming data. You can write tests like so:

```
Sub Test_FlipNames()
    Dim TestCase As String
    Dim ExpectedResult As String
    Dim Result As String

    TestCase = "John Smith"
    ExpectedResult = "Smith, John"
    Result = FlipNames(TestCase, NameFormat.FNLN_TO_LNFN_WITH_COMMA)
    Test_PrintResults TestCase, ExpectedResult, Result

    TestCase = "John Smith"
    ExpectedResult = TestCase
    Result = FlipNames(TestCase, 1000)
    Test_PrintResults TestCase, ExpectedResult, Result

    TestCase = "Smith, John"
    ExpectedResult = "John Smith"
    Result = FlipNames(TestCase, NameFormat.LNFN_WITH_COMMA_TO_FNLN)
    Test_PrintResults TestCase, ExpectedResult, Result

    TestCase = "Smith, John"
    ExpectedResult = TestCase
    Result = FlipNames(TestCase, 1000)
    Test_PrintResults TestCase, ExpectedResult, Result

    TestCase = "John"
    ExpectedResult = "John"
    Result = FlipNames(TestCase, NameFormat.FNLN_TO_LNFN_WITH_COMMA)
    Test_PrintResults TestCase, ExpectedResult, Result

    TestCase = "John"
    ExpectedResult = "John"
    Result = FlipNames(TestCase, NameFormat.LNFN_WITH_COMMA_TO_FNLN)
    Test_PrintResults TestCase, ExpectedResult, Result

End Sub

Sub Test_PrintResults(TestCase As String, ExpectedResult As String, Result As String)
    Debug.Print "Case: " & TestCase & "; Expected: " & ExpectedResult
    Debug.Print IIf(Result = ExpectedResult, "PASS", "FAILED")
End Sub
```

The advantage of such test is that if the function changes, existing tests can be run to ensure that previous functionality hasn't broken. Then add more tests to check if additional code that was added is OK.

To call the function over a range of cells, you can do like the way you had it:

```
Sub FlipNamesInSelection()
    Dim rCell as Range
    For Each rCell in Selection
        rCell.Value = FlipNames(rCell.Value, NameFormat.LNFN_WITH_COMMA_TO_FNLN)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that will flip the names (including any middle names)

```
Sub TestFlipName()
    Debug.Print FlipName("First Middle Last")
    Debug.Print FlipName("Last, First")
End Sub

Function FlipName(sName As String) As String

    Dim i As Long
    Dim NameArray() As String: NameArray = Split(Replace(sName, ",", ""))

    If InStr(sName, ",") Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(NameArray)
            FlipName = FlipName + NameArray(i) + " "
        Next i
        FlipName = FlipName + NameArray(0)
    Else
        FlipName = NameArray(UBound(NameArray)) + ", "
        For i = 1 To UBound(NameArray)
            FlipName = FlipName + NameArray(i - 1) + " "
        Next i
        FlipName = Trim(FlipName)
    End If
End Function
```